# Forward Backward Rule Xml DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I want to model a simple (IF Then) rule using DTD. This is what I have come up with:

```
<!ELEMENT forward    ((rule | fact)*)> 

<!ELEMENT rule       (if, then)> 

<!ELEMENT fact       (#PCDATA)> 

<!ELEMENT if         (#PCDATA)> 

<!ELEMENT then       (#PCDATA)>
```

This is a dtd for a forward rule ( p => c). I want to model the backward rule as well ( c <= p) using conclusion and premise elements instead of if and then. Do I just need to change if and then to cons and prem or do I need to do something else. I appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 0):

XML DTDs simply give you a syntax for your model. You could, for example, write:

```
<rule>
  <if>is raining</if>  
  <then>pigs will fly</then>
</rule>
```

and

```
<rule>
  <cons>pigs will fly</cons>  
  <prem>is raining</prem>
</rule>
```

but you will have to provide any logic connecting these two and write it yourself. XML gives you no specific help.

I would suggest you look at languages such as Prolog.

Answer (score 0):

For an XML vocabulary could do a lot worse than "borrow" the equivalent functionality from XSLT (even if you don't use the same names).

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl:if

The general form of its syntax is

```
<xsl:if test = boolean-expression>
  <!-- Content: template -->
</xsl:if>
```

For forwarding and such-like, your problem is too general to give a precise answer. If you want to chain tests you might give each of your tests an id and then have something like a <forward to-test="some-id"/> element which references the id of the next test to be applied. Or you might build more complicated conditional processing vocabulary, maybe based (again) on XSLT's model (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl:choose).

The DTD gives you syntax but no semantics, so any *functionality* you want around your XML will have to be developed in your application.